# Java: Passing user-agent vars to fetch RSS data from webserver

Tags: java, rss, user-agent

I've been trying to fetch an [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) feed through [java](/questions/tagged/java) and I keep getting a 403 error. I searched around and it's apparently due to empty [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) vars.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
try {
          url = new URL("http://*****.com/feed/");
          InputStream is = null;
          try {

                URLConnection con = url.openConnection();   
                con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
                con.connect();
                is = con.getInputStream();
                feed = FeedParser.parse(con.getURL());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("error");
                try
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }   
            } finally {
                if( is != null)
                    try
                    {
                        is.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (FeedIOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (FeedXMLParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedFeedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

      int items = feed.getItemCount();

      for (int i = 1; i <= items; i++) {

       FeedItem item = feed.getItem(i-1);

       System.out.println(i+" Title: " + item.getTitle());

      }
```

I'm having trouble making it work, I am sure I'm not doing in correctly. The library that I'm using to parse the RSS feed is [feed4j](/questions/tagged/feed4j).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using Superfeedr's [feed API](https://blog.superfeedr.com) for example? You won't have to deal with HTTP or XML parsing issues.

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Thank you for your response. I looked into it and I see that their Java library isn't compiled and there's no build.xml supplied. So, I wouldn't know how to compile it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed4j doesn't support setting the request properties. So you can't do that unless you modify the [FeedParser class](https://github.com/icyleaf/feed4j/blob/master/src/it/sauronsoftware/feed4j/FeedParser.java) to something like this

```
public static Feed parse(URL url, String userAgent) throws IOException, FeedIOException, FeedXMLParseException, UnsupportedFeedException {
    try {
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        if (userAgent != null) {
            con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
        }
        con.connect();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        SAXReader saxReader = new SAXReader();
        Document document = saxReader.read(is);
        int code = FeedRecognizer.recognizeFeed(document);
        switch (code) {
        case FeedRecognizer.RSS_1_0:
            return TypeRSS_1_0.feed(url, document);
        case FeedRecognizer.RSS_2_0:
            return TypeRSS_2_0.feed(url, document);
        case FeedRecognizer.ATOM_0_3:
            return TypeAtom_0_3.feed(url, document);
        case FeedRecognizer.ATOM_1_0:
            return TypeAtom_1_0.feed(url, document);
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedFeedException();
        }
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        throw new FeedXMLParseException(e);
    }
}
```

Also at [github](https://github.com/janih/feed4j)

Comment: I have been trying to find a way to compile the library, but either I'm too dumb or it's impossible without having a build.xml.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I decided to ditch this method, though, since it's got A LOT of dependencies. Instead I'll use jsoup to parse the xml as html and store the data in a HashMap. Thanks so much once again! :)